# How to accomplish inheritance in Elm

Tags: elm

```
type alias Car = { model : Model, year: Int }


type Model = Crv | Enzo | Mustang | Viper

-- I can do this
enzo = Car Enzo -- partial Contructor
> myE<function> : Int -> Repl.Car

myEnzo = enzo 2018 
> { model = Enzo, year = 2018 } : Repl.Car

-- but i CANNOT do this
enzo2017 = Car { year: 2017 } -- INVALID
```

How can i make a simple constructor that doesn't force me to list the attributes in a defined order.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? It's not clear how your example relates to inheritance. Also, you *can't* initialize an instance of `Car` with just a subset of the fields initialized.

Comment: @vijoc really im trying to use partial application with "constructor" function to create pseudo descendent "constructor".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider, when you define this:

```
type alias Car = { model : Model, year: Int, notes: String}
```

what you really get, is a function `Car` like this:

```
> Car
> <function> : Repl.Model -> Int -> String -> Repl.Car
```

It's easy to define another constructor:

```
> f notes model year = Car model year notes
> <function> : String -> Repl.Model -> Int -> Repl.Car
```

Comment: that is awesome, this is what i needed. using destructure with the factory, i think that's probably the ideal solution `createEnzo : { year: Int } -> Car`, any ideas  how to make the signature on the pre-destructure a little easier? e.g. `omit "model" from Car struct`

Comment: If you're eventually getting a Car out of a function, then at some point a Model must go in to the function (OR something that can make a Model.) So we can't avoid the Model on the left hand side. If your car type doesn't always need a field (like notes for example) then you need 2 constructors: `type Car = CarWithNotes Model Int String | CarWithoutNotes Model Int` but now all code that deals with cars needs to consider 2 cases.

Comment: i feel that at some point in the future a better way of building records needs exist in elm in order to really siphon oop people over.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to functional programming we need to "start over" with some concepts. In this case the confusion seems to be with the word constructor. 
The record constructor in Elm is different than the object constructor in object oriented language.

The record constructor does not create a record, it only creates a function that can create records. It does this by partial application.

**In partial application you can only give the arguments in their order**. This is defined in lambda calculus and I believe it is not specific to Elm.
In the case of creating records with record constructor changing the order of the argument doesn't make changes in the result.

We can use this handy function *flip* that returns the same function with reverse order of the arguments:

```
enzo2017 = flip Car 2017
myEnzo2017 = enzo2017 Viper
```

Comment: thanks, that's clever, however it doesn't solve the general case of partially construct a record and there could be readability issues if we have a more complex record / type alias

Comment: I agree that it doesn't solve the problem as defined and I agree for the readability issues which would be terrible with more than two arguments. However try to leave your way of thinking from object oriented paradigm and see if you actually need partially constructing a record. This is one of the safety mechanisms of Elm that helps preventing bugs.
When I first ran into this, I tried tunring some variables into Maybes. Using the records like that was wrong in the end. But the exercise made me think why/where do I need Maybes and the implications of using "partial" records.